# Why is Nativescript on ios so slow?

Tags: nativescript

In my app, I timed the duration it takes to navigate to one particular screen.

In Android simulator about 700 ms and about the same or faster on the device.

In IOS simulator about the same but on the device over 4000ms - 5x slower!

On the device in debug mode but on the release version also super slow.

I'm trying on iPhone 6.

What could cause such a slowdown?

Do I need to optimize the build - config file somewhere.

Maybe the iPhone6 has a processor that needs to be built for - arm???

Comment: That's totally opposite of how I generally see it. iOS is lot faster than Android in most cases. Without a sample or knowing what you have in your app or in that particular pages, it's quite difficult to comment on this. I would suggest you to try timeline view or iOS instruments to debug what's taking so long.

Comment: But there's a similar disparity between the ios simulator (iphone 8 i think) and the device (iphone 6s).

Comment: The page has an AbsoluteLayout with about 150 children that I add dynamically. The major time seems to be consumed between `navigatingTo` and `loaded` event. I assume it's during this time that the native child View objects are being created. Again same app runs much faster on Android and ios simulator.

Comment: Can you explain why you need absolute layout and why 150 children which sounds like too many views to render in a page.

Comment: The page contains a calendar like view - but also with bar Labels that span across dates...2-3 months and it adds up. Ideally I would like something like JS Canvas but I don't think I have that in NS. I tried it on a iPhone 10 device and it takes about 1.3secs - that seems tolerable. It seems like creating a lot of Label objects on iPhone 6 (12.4) is very slow - taking about 4 secs. On Android 0.7secs.

Comment: Indeed, also I still don't understand why you need absolute layout here. Too much load on layout could cause it, you may have to rethink of your layouts

Comment: I used that layout because I need fine control over where to position the horizontal bars - like timeline - they also span across multiple dates. Just think of a project planner page. Regardless of what I chose, I think the issue is why it's taking so much longer on the ios version. The page dynamically creates about 150-200 Label objects. The Android version does the same and is much faster. That is the question for NS developers - find the reason. If they fix the issue for 200 objects - it'll be that much faster for the rest of the developers when they add less objects.